# "There are currently 0 active bounties"

Tags: feature-request, bounties, advertising

On the home page of Skeptics.SE, I just saw an ad saying

> There are currently 00 active bounties, worth + 0

While the statement is true, and has correct pluralization, it's kind of … useless. Can such an ad not be shown while there's no active bounties?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: One might argue it's useful for encouraging someone to set a bounty somewhere...but the superfluous zeroes seem...superfluous...

Comment: Where exactly did you see such ad?

Comment: @ShadowWizard screenshot added. Godzilla ate the freehand circles.

Comment: Seems like a fun site!

Comment: Sometimes it's good to highlight the absence of something in order to encourage changing it.

Comment: Where does it link to?

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange

Comment: It links me to [the featured tab](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) (as expected).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am one of the creators of this ad. We don't currently have any logic in place to show a different image when there are no bounties, but we could. I'll ask Nathan Greenstein and see if he'd be willing to make something. What would you like it to look like?

**edit:** This is what we came up with:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP means to simply not show the ad when there are no bounties, so it's up to the dev team.

Comment: How about something that encourages bounties? A statement like "Saw an interesting question without any good answers. How about placing a bounty?" or something in the banner. I personally think even when there are no bounties, the ad is good in the sense that it encourages the use of an on-site feature (and bounties in general lead to the generation of better than normal content). (Also, the ad looks great!)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I doubt the dev team wants to special-case this, but one option would be to just serve up a transparent image. The markup on the page forces the size so it'll effectively be a hole on the page.

Comment: @AsheeshR Thanks! Yeah, encouraging users to add bounties is a good idea. I'm not sure if linking to the bounties page still makes sense in that case, but it probably wouldn't be terrible.

Comment: You could link it to the unanswered tab in that case, if that's possible.

Comment: I'm happy either with not showing if there's no bounties, or encouraging people to add bounties (but what if they lack the rep to do so?)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm OK, we'll try and create a special message for 0 bounties, maybe sometime this weekend.

Comment: @KyleCronin I hope working weekends is a normal thing, rather than specially for this feature request!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but will the dimensions of this ad be updated to accommodate the new sidebar width?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I'm looking into it

Answer (score 3):

It's a Community Promotion Ad: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2586/6781

If you dislike it, you can downvote and with <6 score it won't show on the front page anymore.

You can also leave a comment to the author, but I think it's an intended pun.

Last but not least, when you hover the ad you see such thing:

> [image]

The area in circle is a [bug specific to Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/links-in-promotion-ads-are-black-on-black-thus-invisible) due to its black theme, it should say "comment" and "stats" and link to the above post, thus preventing confusion.